# HTML div background stretch

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i stretch background in div, while background would stretch to fit the screen resolution. In that div i want to have just navBar located top-right. Want this div just for intro page. There will be more content in others div behind that.

Comment: what about using `background-size:cover;`

Comment: this is the same, point is that i want to stretch background to fit screen resolution not just div that contain navbar with heigh and width 200px+-, maybe i need stretch div or i dont know

Answer (score 0):

background-size:100%;
to your css underneath background-image.

choose the dimension that  you want

background-size: 30px 40px;

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  width      : 100vw;
  height     : 100vh;
  background : url('path/to-image.jpg') 50%/contain;
}
```

If you don't care about stretching and or distorting the image, then you can do what Melik said and set background value to...

`background : url('path/to-image.jpg') 50%/100% 100%;`

Comment: @uppermost np! if this is what you were looking for select it as the answer ;)